# How to run a mindtct package (NBIS software)for a entire database(a set of 100 images) at a time in Redhat Linux

Tags: image-processing, fingerprint, biometrics

I have installed NBIS software in Redhat Linux in VMware and running as a host OS in my windows 7 system.
Till now I executed giving only one image, but now I need to run the entire DB with 100 images at a time and I should get the extracted minutiae.

I use the below cmd:

```
/NBIS/src/bin/mindtct /NBIS/Test_4.1.0/mindtct/data/5_2.jpg 
/NBIS/output/5_2.xyt
```

Can anyone resolve my issue? What cmd should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script to loop over all the images in your collection, or better yet, write a C program to wrap the `mindtct` functions, doing whatever you want to do within your new app.  Take a look at the source for the binary `mindtct` in NBIS, especially the `get_minutiae()` function.

Comment: `get_minutiae()` is in the file `getmin.c`.

Answer (score 1):

In the folder with your images you can use a bash script. This is the relevant part from mine. A simple for loop that will convert all images with the extension jp2 to xyt images.

```
PHOTOTYPE="*.jp2"
SAVEPATH="path/to/save/folder/"

for PIC in $PHOTOTYPE
do
    echo "Processing mindtct -m1 $PIC $SAVEPATH/$PIC"
    mindtct -m1 "$PIC" "$SAVEPATH/$PIC"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on Raspbian to Raspberry Pi
./mindtct path/file.jpg path/output
and it produced 8 files:
.brw, .dm, .hcm, .lcm, .lfm, .min, .qm, .xyt

In my understanding you should use a mindtct function to compare two finger images.

Comment: According to [user's guide to NBIS](http://www.nist.gov/customcf/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=51097) (page 3 and 4): `MINDTCT` is a minutiae detection system. To compare fingerprints a fingerprint matching system called `BOZORTH3` should be used.